# linux vim pasting directory path in editor

Tags: linux, vim

I am trying to do the following:
Being in Vim, I want to be able to easily yank a path and paste it in a file.

I use the following method:

- (0) I installed **`Ranger`** and **`Xsel`**
- (1) In vim, run `:!ranger` to open ranger in your vim window;
- (2) Navigate to the directory/file whose location you want to copy;
- (3) Press `y` (yank) followed by d to yank the directory only, `n` to yank the filename only, or `p` to yank directory/filename.
- (4) Press `q` to quit, then any key to return to vim.
- (5) In insert mode, middleclick or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd> to paste, or in normal mode, `"*p` to paste.

However this only paste whatever is in the clipboard beforehand.
I tried setting `:set clipboard=unnamed` but it doesn't change anything

Comment: 1) I tried the pwd command and i can see it is returning the name of the current dir; the :!ranger command allows me to browse to look for any dir which is what i am after
2) can you briefly tell me what is the !r command (sorry im noob...)

Comment: You have an option to paste file names in vim. Try Ctrl+x and Ctrl+f. This will allow you to type files and choose subdirectory from popup

Answer (score 2):

Or simply use, vim's auto-completion, which in your case will be `Ctrl-X Ctrl-f`.

For example, we start by typing initial few characters of the file path, `etc/`,
Then type `ctrl-x` followed by `ctrl-f`. Upon this, vim show list of files under `/etc`

Answer (score 1):

alternative solution to get a file path in vim:
:r!ls /home/.../.../file.txt